# OAuth provider that is an OpenID consumer?

Tags: oauth, openid

I would like to use OpenID to unify logins across projects that my group is working on.  One of the projects may need to be an OAuth provider in the future so that users can sync data with other sites as well.  Is it possible to setup an OAuth Provider that uses OpenID for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Not sure which version of OAuth your are talking about here. But basically it would entail making the OAuth authorization step into an OpenID process which when successfully completed, resumes the OAuth process.

NB: OAuth is primarily for authorization of third party applications, OpenID is for user authentication. There is nothing impossible about mashing up the two, they are in essence dealing with different problem domains.

Comment: Our group is based at NAFHA.org, but we have a data gathering project located on NAHERP.com.  NAFHA.org would be the primary place for registration, and the logins would need to work on NAFHA projects like NAHERP.com.  There are other projects that people can enter their finds to as well, and there has been an expressed interest in allowing people to sync their data to other projects.  So openId would be used to unify the logins accross NAFHA projects, but OAuth would be used specifically to allow users to sync their data to other projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Authentication(OpenID) or OAuth both require your permission, but there is an important difference. With Basic Authentication, you provide your username and password for the app to access application, and the application has to store and send this information over the Internet each time you use the app. OAuth attempts to provide a standard way for developers to offer their services via an API without forcing their users to expose their passwords (and other credentials).

It doesn’t mean to say we cannot use the two together. OAuth talks about getting users to grant access while OpenID talks about making sure the users are really who they say they are. They should work great together.

[Here is an example(OpenID+OAuth Hybrid protocol)](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) lets aware you, how to use hybrid protocol.

Twitter, Facebook are working on now OAuth only while
Google, Yahoo work on OpenID as well as OAuth.